# Send HTTP Post parameters from an NSDictionary to a web service

Tags: ios, http

I have a R.E.S.T web service waiting to received GET and POST Http Request.

I've built a class for creating, sending and move the delegation instances of those requests.

From some reason, my parameters in POST method doesn't being sent correctly and the result is a request time out (the server doesn't response at all).

I think it might be something with the format i'm create the request body it:

```
- (NSURLConnection*)requestUrl:(NSString *)url usingMethod:(NSString *)method containingData:(NSDictionary *)data {
    NSString* dataString = [self createStringFromData:data];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    if ([method isEqualToString:HTTP_REQUEST_GET])
        request = [self createGetRequest:request withData:dataString];
    else if ([method isEqualToString:HTTP_REQUEST_POST])
        request = [self createPostRequest:request withData:dataString];
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *errorDetail = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [errorDetail setValue:@"Http Request Method is Invalid" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.picomedia.Pico" code:100 userInfo:errorDetail];
        [_httpRequestDelegate httpRequestReturnedError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    //set request time out
    //show the url and datastring if in debug mode
    #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Url: %@",[request.URL absoluteString]);
        NSLog(@"Method: %@", method);
        NSLog(@"DataString: %@", dataString);
    #else
        request.timeoutInterval = 15;
    #endif
    // Create url connection and fire request
    return [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

/**
 Create string from a data dictionary.
 @param data the dictionary to take the data from
 @return the string containing the data
 */
-(NSString*) createStringFromData:(NSDictionary*) data {
    NSString* dataString = @"";
    for(NSString* key in data)
    {
        NSString* value = (NSString*)[data objectForKey:key];
        NSString* keyValuePair = [[[key stringByAppendingString:@"="] stringByAppendingString:[self urlEncodeString:value]] stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
        dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString:keyValuePair];
    }
    if ([dataString length] > 0)
        dataString = [dataString substringToIndex:[dataString length] - 1];
    return dataString;
}

/**
 Create an HTTP GET request with data
 @param request the NSMutableURLRequest request
 @param data the string containging key->value pairs of the data. the data should me utf8 and urlencoded
 @return NSMutableURLRequest with the request data
 */
- (NSMutableURLRequest*) createGetRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request withData:(NSString*)data {
    request.HTTPMethod = HTTP_REQUEST_GET;
    if (data != nil)
    {
        NSString* url = [[[request.URL absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@"?"]stringByAppendingString:data];
        request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    }
    return request;
}

/**
 Send an Http POST request with a string containg the post data
 @param data the data of the request in string format
 */
- (NSMutableURLRequest*) createPostRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request withData:(NSString*) data {
    request.HTTPMethod = HTTP_REQUEST_POST;
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data length]];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
   NSData *requestBodyData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
    // Create url connection and fire request
    return request;
}
```

btw, when sending empty data it works, meaning it does send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do the request building yourself you should get inspired by the AFNetworking part that does this work. The library does exactly what you want to do [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m#L304-L328):

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(id)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSParameterAssert(method);
    NSParameterAssert(URLString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    NSParameterAssert(url);

    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    mutableRequest.HTTPMethod = method;
    mutableRequest.allowsCellularAccess = self.allowsCellularAccess;
    mutableRequest.cachePolicy = self.cachePolicy;
    mutableRequest.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = self.HTTPShouldHandleCookies;
    mutableRequest.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = self.HTTPShouldUsePipelining;
    mutableRequest.networkServiceType = self.networkServiceType;
    mutableRequest.timeoutInterval = self.timeoutInterval;

    mutableRequest = [[self requestBySerializingRequest:mutableRequest withParameters:parameters error:error] mutableCopy];

    return mutableRequest;
}
```

Than there is several implementations of `requestBySerializingRequest:withParameters:error:` depending on the encoding you want to use for your request.

I hope it will help.

Comment: This is actually a great framework and it simplify everything. Thanks!